# Обойти все id с getElementById

Tags: javascript

```
<table>

    <tr id="conteiner_top">
        <td>Занято</td>
        <td>Занято</td>
        <td>Занято</td>
        <td>Занято</td>
        <td>Занято</td>
    </tr>

</table>

<table>

    <tr id="conteiner_top">
        <td>Занято 2</td>
        <td>Занято 2</td>
        <td>Занято 2</td>
        <td>Занято 2</td>
        <td>Занято 2</td>
    </tr>

</table>


<script>
    n_top = document.getElementById('conteiner_top').getElementsByTagName('td');
    console.log(n_top);
    while(n_top.length < 10)
    {
        document.getElementById('conteiner_top').innerHTML += '<td>Свободно</td>';
        n_top = document.getElementById('conteiner_top').getElementsByTagName('td');
    }
</script>
```

Как и должно быть в js он увидел только первый `conteiner_top`. Как правильно обработать все? С `getElementsByClassName` как то не заладилось у нас.

Comment: `С getElementsByClassName как то не заладилось у нас.` - это и есть правильный способ

Comment: Использовать несколько одинаковых id запрещено, у вас должно заладиться с `getElementsByClassName` :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант тоже:
Не забудь id на class поменять и тогда это сработает.

```
document.querySelector(".container_top td");
```

А конкретные элементы перебирай как массив.
Например:

```js
var firstTable = document.querySelectorAll(".container_top")[0];
firstTable.documentGetElementsByTagName("td")[2] //вернет 3 ячейку первого ряда;
```

Если элемент с с классом один, то `document.querySelector(".yourClass")`, а если их несколько, то `document.querySelectorAll(".yourClass")`.

Answer (score 0):

С getElementById не получится, но можно с помощью метода querySelectorAll:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id='conteiner_top']")
```

Comment: А почему так нельзя `document.querySelectorAll("#conteiner_top")`? Зачем объявлять SelectorAll для id? Id должен быть уникальным у элементов..

Comment: "Id должен быть уникальным у элементов"  

Конечно, логичнее заменить id на class, если это возможно.